# Ввести координаты и получить значение ячейки DataGridView в C#

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Есть таблица DataGridView с данными: например 6 столбцов и 4 строки.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы можно было вручную ввести (в текстбоксы) координаты определённой ячейки, например строка 3, столбец 2 и вывести данные с этой ячейки в TextBox. Также нужно, чтобы это выполнялось независимо от того, выделена ли мышью какая-то ячейка в DataGridView.

Как это будет выглядеть в коде?

Comment: вы как то сами пытались решить вашу задачу?

Comment: Чтобы получить ячейку укажите индексы в квадратных скобках: `dataGridView[columnIndex, rowIndex]`.

Comment: Кстати, что используете: WinForms, WPF или, может, у вас вообще веб-приложение?

Comment: tym32167, сам попробовал бы, но незнаю, какие свойства и методы для этого использовать.

Comment: Alexander Petrov, WinForms

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, попробовал 'dataGridView[columnIndex, rowIndex]' , однако из-за события *dataGridView1_SelectionChanged* выводится только столбец той строки, которая выделена мышью. Можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы выборка ячейки была независима от события SelectionChanged ?

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, поместите в него код, как делаете. При чём тут вообще событие? Какие индексы передадите, данные той ячейки и получите.

Answer (score 4):

Не поняла вашего беспокойства по поводу `SelectionChanged`. Получение значения ячейки зависит только от указанных вами индексов строки и столбца.

Допустим, вам надо записать значение ячейки из таблицы `dataGridView1`в `label`, тогда, учитывая, что вы заранее получили ранее введенные в `textBox'ы` индексы ячейки и столбца:

```
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[cell].Value);
```

либо так:

```
label2.Text = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1[cell, row].Value);
```

Ну и, конечно, если не знаете методов и свойств, не стесняйтесь заглядывать в MSDN:

1. [Про DataGridView](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/datagridview-control-windows-forms)
2. [Про работу со строками и столбцами](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/basic-column-row-and-cell-features-wf-datagridview-control)

Comment: Третьим надо было "про работу с двумерными массивами".